# Amateur Python Sudoku Solver

Tags: python, object-oriented, python-3.x, sudoku

I'm self-taught in Python and would have a lot of room for improvement. I made this basic Sudoku Solver mainly in order to practice the use of Class creation. I would greatly appreciate any feedback about how I could program any of this in a better way.

```
from math import ceil

class Cell(object):
    def __init__(self, position):
        #input: position of cell each from 1-81
        #output: a Sudoku cell with a row, column and block, a status of blank,
        #and a list of possible values 1-9
        self.position = position
        self.row = ceil(position/9)
        self.col = (position - 1) % 9 + 1
        self.block = ceil(self.col/3) + ceil(self.row/3) * 3 - 3
        self.status = 'blank'
        self.value = 0
        self.possibleValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    def __repr__(self):
        #print description of cell's current state
        startText = 'Cell #' + str(self.position) + ', Status: ' + self.status + ', '
        if self.status == 'blank':
            return  startText + 'Possible values: ' + str(self.possibleValues)
        else:
            return startText + 'Value: ' + str(self.value)
    def populate_cell(self, status, value):
        #input: the cell status of 'given' or 'solved' and the cell value
        #output: set the cell value and status, clear possible values
        self.value = value
        self.status = status
        self.possibleValues = []

class Grid(object):
    def __init__(self, startingValues):
        #input: dictionary of starting values {position 1-81 : value 1-9}
        #positions not given will start blank/zero
        self.status = 'open'
        self.solvedCellsCount = 0
        self.grid = []
        #populate the full grid with blank cells
        for position in range(81):
            self.grid.append(Cell(position + 1))
        #populate given cells (the starting position of the grid)
        for position in startingValues:
            self.grid[position - 1].populate_cell('given', startingValues[position])
            self.solvedCellsCount += 1
    def __repr__(self):
        #print 9 x 9 view of Sudoku grid with pipe separators
        #list to hold the 9 rows
        gridRows = []
        #create 9 row strings and append into gridRows list
        xCell = 0
        for row in range(9):
            compileRow = ''
            for col in range(9):
                compileCell = '|' + str(self.grid[xCell].value) + '|'
                compileRow = compileRow + compileCell
                xCell += 1
            gridRows.append(compileRow)
        #print each row string on a new line
        return '\n'.join(gridRows)
    def solve(self):
        #attempt to solve the puzzle
        #to track whether cells were solved in the current loop (True to enter loop)
        solvedCells = True
        loopCount = 0
        #continue to loop if cells were solved in the last loop
        while solvedCells:
            loopCount += 1
            #begin tracker as False
            solvedCells = False
            #loop through all cells in grid
            for compareCell in self.grid:
                #every non-blank cell takes its turn as the 'compare cell'
                if compareCell.status != 'blank':
                    #sub-loop through all cells in grid as the 'target cell' for solving
                    for targetCell in self.grid:
                        #if the target cell is blank
                        if targetCell.status == 'blank':
                            #check if the target cell shares its row, column or
                            #block with the compare cell
                            if targetCell.row == compareCell.row or \
                            targetCell.col == compareCell.col or \
                            targetCell.block == compareCell.block:
                                #if the compare cell's value is still listed as a
                                #possible value of the target cell, remove it
                                if compareCell.value in targetCell.possibleValues:
                                    targetCell.possibleValues.remove(compareCell.value)
            #loop through all cells in grid
            for targetCell in self.grid:
                #every blank cell takes its turn as the target cell to be solved
                if targetCell.status == 'blank':
                    #if only one possible value remains
                    if len(targetCell.possibleValues) == 1:
                        #solve the cell
                        targetCell.populate_cell('solved', targetCell.possibleValues[0])
                        #increment the grid's solved cells count
                        self.solvedCellsCount += 1
                        #set the solved cells tracker to True
                        solvedCells = True
                #if all 81 cells are solved
                if self.solvedCellsCount == 81:
                    #set the grid status to solved and end the loop
                    self.status = 'solved'
                    break
        #print puzzle result
        if self.status == 'solved':
            print('Puzzle solved in ' + str(loopCount) + ' loops:')
        else:
            print('Solver ran for ' + str(loopCount) + ' loops before reaching a dead end:')
        print(self)

easyPuzzle1875322053 = {5:3, 6:7, 7:8,
                        11:9, 16:3, 17:5, 18:2,
                        20:5, 26:7,
                        28:3, 29:8, 30:2, 31:6, 33:9, 35:4,
                        38:7, 39:9, 40:4, 42:3, 43:2, 44:6,
                        47: 4, 49:8, 51:5, 52:9, 53:3, 54:7,
                        56:3, 62:2,
                        64:9, 65:2, 66:8, 71:1,
                        75:6, 76:3, 77:4}

myPuzzle = Grid(easyPuzzle1875322053)
print('Starting grid:')
print(myPuzzle)
myPuzzle.solve()
```

Comment: Can you explain the input format representation?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly, but do you mean how you input the puzzle? If so, you submit a dictionary of cell positions (1-81) and their starting values. So in the given puzzle cell #5 (top row, fifth column) starts as a 3. I hope that answers your question?